# Javascript click() event not working on WP8 built Cordova and jQuery Mobile. Android and iOS the same code is running fine

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have recently started developing for WP8 platform. My app works perfectly with android and iOS phones.

> index.html

```
<a id="fail" href="#page2" onclick="alert('test');">Page 1 link</a>
```

> index.js

`$('#fail').click();`

> Issue

I can see the alert box in the WP8 phone **but my phone do not redirect the JQM page with id page2.**
 However when I manually touch/tap the link "Page 1 link" , I get the popup alert and after that I get redirected to page 2 as expected.

Please let me know the solution if you are aware of the same. I am literally frustrated with this issue for the past 9 hours :(

Although I have found out some work around by using :

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page2", { transition: "slideup" });
```

But changing so much code in my large scale app will be another problem as I plan to maintain uniform code base for all 3 environments. :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [Content security policy](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-security-whitlists/) try to add **unsafe-inline** to **default-src** to enable inline JavaScript.

> script-src 'unsafe-inline'    Allows use of inline source elements such as style attribute, onclick, or script tag bodies (depends on the context of the source it is applied to)

Comment: I have added the below line in the header. **<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">** But nothing happened :(

Comment: If you keep only the href (without onclick event) it redirect correctly?

Comment: No that is not an issue. If I physically click/tap then the redirection is occurring irrespective of the onclick attribute. However via JS its not irrespective of the onclick attribute. I have added the onclick attribute to check whether the JS click event is getting triggered or not.